# magento 2: how to display region name in dropdown

Tags: magento2, drop-downs, country-regions, regions

Hi to all I added Italian region name in magento db by SQL in directory_country_region as follows:

```
INSERT INTO directory_country_region(country_id, code, default_name) VALUES ('IT', 'TO', 'Torino'); 
INSERT INTO directory_country_region(country_id, code, default_name) VALUES ('IT', 'VC', 'Vercelli'); 
INSERT INTO directory_country_region(country_id, code, default_name) VALUES ('IT', 'NO', 'Novara'); [...]
```

I also handled directory_country_region_name like this:

```
INSERT INTO directory_country_region_name (locale, region_id, name)
SELECT 'it_IT', dcr.region_id, dcr.code
FROM directory_country_region dcr
WHERE dcr.country_id = 'IT';

INSERT INTO directory_country_region_name (locale, region_id, name)
SELECT 'en_US', dcr.region_id, dcr.code
FROM directory_country_region dcr
WHERE dcr.country_id = 'IT';
```

clicking on the dropdown I'm not able to see the region name and I get this result: 
 [image: dropdown list] I'd like to see 'Agrigento' instead of 'AG' (e.g.)
Any idea of what I'm missing? Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by myself. I replaced the second Sql code as here below:

```
INSERT INTO directory_country_region_name (locale, region_id, name)
SELECT 'it_IT', dcr.region_id, dcr.default_name
FROM directory_country_region dcr
WHERE dcr.country_id = 'IT';

INSERT INTO directory_country_region_name (locale, region_id, name)
SELECT 'en_US', dcr.region_id, dcr.default_name
FROM directory_country_region dcr
WHERE dcr.country_id = 'IT';
```